# Errors on https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Tags: package-management

I'm working on some offline package deployments, and usually, I grab packages from https://packages.ubuntu.com/, however it seems that the package lists for xenial, bionic, cosmic etc, are all empty.  Trusty is returning results and seems to be behaving normally.

If I try to go direct to a package, it seems that it just doesn't exist any more: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libc++abi-dev

Is this just me?

Thanks!

Comment: no, I've experienced the same issue a few minutes ago

Comment: Thanks - glad I'm not going mad. Is there somewhere that's recommended to notify Canonical of the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I just registered for Ubuntu One and raised a bug against the Package website. Hopefully some will fix it soon. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message? If yes, please [edit] it into the question. **Edit**: nvm, I thought you were talking about `apt` but I see the website is the problem, e.g. the [Bionic package list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages?format=txt.gz) is empty but the [Trusty package list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/allpackages?format=txt.gz) seems fine. And just to mention a more familiar package that's missing, [apt for Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/apt).

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't getting a page error as such, it was more than the list of packages which normally is shown, was just empty. The page itself was loading fine. I believe it has been fixed now though - this page, for instance, returns a full list of results: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/

Comment: If memory serves,  packages.ubuntu.com is not a small-c canonical reference for package information while the rmadison command is instead.  I have no clue where that is documented.